# Variable names truncated in outhistogram dataset in SAS 9.1.3

Tags: unix, sas

If I run the following in SAS 9.4 (University Edition), the `outhistogram` dataset shows the full names of the two variables. However, if I do the same thing in SAS 9.1.3 (in a UNIX environment) only the first 8 characters of the variable names are kept.

Is there any workaround for this? If not, what was the earliest version of SAS in which this behaviour changed?

```
proc univariate data = sashelp.cars noprint;
    var mpg_highway horsepower;
    histogram /midpoints = 5 10 15 outhistogram = example;
run;
```

I have tried using the `namelen` option as suggested below, but this does not appear to be valid in my version of SAS:

```
210     proc univariate data = sashelp.orsales noprint namelen=32;
                                                       -------
                                                       22
                                                       76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, ALL, ALPHA, ANNOTATE, CIBASIC,
              CIPCTLDF, CIPCTLNORMAL, CIQUANTDF, CIQUANTNORMAL, DATA, DEBUG, EXCLNPWGT, FREQ,
              GOUT, LOCCOUNT, MODE, MODES, MU0, NEXTROBS, NEXTRVAL, NOBYPLOT, NOPRINT, NORMAL,
              PCTLDEF, PLOT, PLOTSIZE, ROBUSTSCALE, ROUND, TRIMMED, VARDEF, WINSORIZED.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

I also tried setting `option validvarname = any` but this made no difference to the outhistogram dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Try NAMELEN option.

```
proc univariate data = sashelp.cars noprint namelen=32;
var mpg_highway horsepower;
histogram /midpoints = 5 10 15 outhistogram = example;
run;
```

Comment: Sorry, not a valid option in 9.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    Options validvarname=any;
But I'm surprised, long var names were introduced in v7.

Comment: Sorry, no effect in 9.1.3